# How to extract the first column from a tsv file?

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have a file containing some data and I want to use only the first column as a stdin for my script, but I'm having trouble extracting it.
I tried using this

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $1}' inputs.tsv
```

but it only shows the first letter of the first column. I tried some other things but it either shows the entire file or just the first letter of the first column.

My file looks something like this:

```
Harry_Potter    1
Lord_of_the_rings    10
Shameless    23
....
```

Comment: your input doesn't look as tab-separated. Post the expected result

Comment: If that script does what you say then there are control characters in your input file messing with the output. The awk script is correct as written.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `cut` which is available on all Unix and Linux systems:

```
cut -f1 inputs.tsv
```

You don't need to specify the `-d` option because tab is the default delimiter.  From `man cut`:

> ```
>  -d delim
>          Use delim as the field delimiter character instead of the tab character.
> ```

As Benjamin has rightly stated, your `awk` command is indeed correct.  Shell passes literal \t as the argument and awk does interpret it as a tab, while other commands like `cut` may not.

Not sure why you are getting just the first character as the output.

---

You may want to take a look at this post:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601)

Comment: I don't think you're correct in saying that `"\t"` doesn't translate to a tab. The shell won't touch it in double quotes, and awk then *does* interpret `\t` as a tab. Additionally, `$'\t'` is Bash only. I'm pretty sure that `awk -F"\t" '{print $1}'` is a POSIX compliant way of printing the first tab separated field of each line. Example: `awk --posix -F"\t" '{print $1}' <<< $'1\t2'`

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. for correcting me.  I have updated the answer to include your explanation.

Comment: @BenjaminW. is correct and `awk -F'\t'` is fine, you do not need the bashism of `awk -F$'\t'`. The different between single and double quotes is also not relevant in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (better rely on a real [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) parser...):

```
csvcut -c 1 -f $'\t' file
```

Check [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/#)

### Output :

```
Harry_Potter
Lord_of_the_rings
Shameless
```

### Note :

As @RomanPerekhrest said, you should fix your broken sample input (we saw spaces where tabs are expected...)

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit. I seem to have problem with the -f arguments, I get an error message that the argument is unrecognized

Comment: Which shell are you using ? Try with [tag:bash]